# How can I group multiple columns in different ways finding new occurrences?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataset in this format:

```
bill_id patient_id Date_of_purchase
14           321      23-4-17
29           123      25-4-17
29           123      25-4-17
29           123      25-4-17
35           321      28-6-18
35           321      28-6-18
```

For the same `bill_id`, the row of purchase belongs to the same bill.
For the same `patient_id`, it corresponds to the same person.
`Date` is the date when the purchase was made.

What I want to do is to figure out the number of old and new customers who made a purchase from any start date to any given date. It counts as old if the person's patient id had already made a purchase before. Rest are new.

Is there any standard pandas function to group and compare multiple columns like this based on different conditions?

Something like the following function and output:

```
foo(start_date, end_date):

   return old customers, new customers.
## E.g. foo(19-4-17,30-6-19) is (1,1) as patient_id number 321 came twice and is hence counted as old.
```

Comment: is there a standard function to do what your asking to the T? nope, are there multiple functions you can use to get to your goal, yes. Can you add in your ideal output

Comment: @Datanovice oh damn. okay. Can you show a bit how to do it? I have edited the post for the required output as you asked. Thankyou so much for the help :)!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code snippet runs on its own and uses some groupby and merging magic:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({"bill_id": [1, 1, 2, 3, 3], 
                   "patient_id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 4], 
                   "date": [datetime(2020, 1, 1), 
                            datetime(2020, 1, 2), 
                            datetime(2020, 1, 3), 
                            datetime(2020, 1, 4), 
                            datetime(2020, 1, 5)]
})

start_date = datetime(2020, 1, 2)
end_date = datetime(2020, 1, 5)

first_purchase = df.groupby(["patient_id"]).agg({"date": "min"})
first_purchase["first_purchase"] = 1
df = df.merge(first_purchase, how="left").fillna(0).astype({"first_purchase": "int"}).rename(columns={"first_purchase": "new_purchase"})
df["old_purchase"] = 1-df["new_purchase"]

idx = (df["date"]>=start_date)&(df["date"]<=end_date)
df.loc[idx, "new_purchase"].sum(), df.loc[idx, "old_purchase"].sum()
```

### Explanation

We first groupby `patient_id` and get the minimum dates (i.e. the date the patient first purchased). For those dates and `patient_id`s, we set the "new_purchase" columns to true. The "old_purchase" column is just the inverse. Finally, we select the subset of the data by date and sum over the respective columns.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for this. I think it's correct except you are still not taking into count one person making multiple purchases every time he comes to the store.  So for example in my example in description, bill_id: 29 corresponds to one visit  by one person in which two things were bought. I need to count that as one customer. Your code counts it as two.

Comment: `df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='bill_id')` solved it :)!! Thanks.